# Adding a number to a date

Tags: php, date, date-time

I confess... My php skills are bad.

I'm trying to show an events duration within a post in an events category. Example: Oct 11-14 But I'm having a problem adding an integer to a date then printing it in the correct format. Please see my code below:

```
<span class="news-item-date-day">
  <?php the_time('M j');

    $event_length = get_post_meta
    ($post->ID, 'event_length', $single = true);

    if($event_length !== '') {
      echo '-' . (intval(the_time('j')) + intval($event_length)); 
    } 

  ?>
</span>
```

the_time is Oct 11. The $event_length is 3. But the above code prints Oct 1111-3, not Oct 11-14.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `date( 'M j', time()+(DAY_IN_SECONDS*3) )` replace 3 with the days to add.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the `event_length` meta data might be? Is it a timestamp? Or a number? Or a date? (and if so, in which format)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic '$event_length' is a Custom Field with the value of 3.

Comment: @SamuelElh The above function isn't what I need. It take the current date and adds 3. I think easiest thing would be to convert `the_time('j')` into a number then add `$event_length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `get_the_time`, not `the_time` to *get* the date (the latter *echo*'s the value). You also need to re-evaluate how you're trying to calculate the end date - you can't just "add" the number of days. What if the event length was 3 but the start date was the 31st?

```
if ( $event_length ) {
    // Get the unix timestamp of the post
    $post_time = get_the_time( 'U' );

    // Increase the timestamp by the event length
    $end_time = $post_time + $event_length * DAY_IN_SECONDS;

    // Conditional date format depending on if the event ends in the same month
    if ( date( 'm', $post_time ) !== date( 'm', $end_time ) )
        echo date_i18n( ' - M j', $end_time );
    else
        echo date_i18n( ' - j', $end_time );
}
```